Conversion of the Cubemap direction access vector to UV coordinates
In GLSL, cubemaps within a shader can be read with
gvec4 texture(gsamplerCube sampler,
    vec3 P,
    [float bias]);

so a direction is used. How can the direction vector P be converted to layer number and uv coordinates of the cubemap and vice versa?

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Cubemap_Texture#Upload_and_orientation

Thank you first, I assume that the absolute highest of the 3 values of the direction vector represents the layer number as follows:
PositiveX -> layer 0,
NegativeX -> layer 1,
PositiveY -> layer 2,
NegativeY -> layer 3,
PositiveZ -> layer 4,
NegativeZ -> layer 5

But how does the UV mapping work?
